# Different index.html file + different url + nginx configuration

Tags: node.js, nginx

I have my angular project running in my server. No i want to serve different **index.html** for different URL as follows:..

```
URL:abc.com/abc
Should load an index.html file with some branding related to `abc` 

URL:abc.com/xyz
Should load an index.html file with some branding related to `xyz`
```

What i approached is created 2 folders separate for abc, xyz with all my frontend code and configured the nginx as follows:

```
location /abc {
alias   /home/root/abc;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
       }

location /xyz {
alias   /home/root/xyz;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
       }
```

But i am getting error as Uncaught `SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in polyfilss.js, runtime.js`. Whether the approach is right? please share your ideas.

Comment: Do you mean you want to receive `/home/root/abc/index.html` for a `example.com/abc` request and `/home/root/xyz/index.html` for a `example.com/xyz` request?

Comment: @Ivan Shatsky Yes exactly. Whether its a good idea?? please suggest some ideas .

Answer (score 1):

I'd say, Instead of using alias, Use root.

> It's better to use root directive instead of alias.

Alias with try_files has a long time bug. 
For more you can checkout alias bug with try_files at https://trac.nginx.org/nginx/ticket/97

```
Nginx.conf For Url abc.com/xyz and /abc 

....
error_page  404  /404.html;

location /abc {
root   /home/root/abc;
index  index.html index.htm;
}

location /xyz {
root   /home/root/xyz;
index  index.html index.htm;
}
location / {
root   /home/root/;
index  index.html index.htm;
}
.....
```

Comment: Thanks, but my question is how can i serve 2 different html page for 2 different urls??

Comment: @Subburaj , I've updated nginx.conf code accordingly.it's a working code

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
root /home/root;

location /abc {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /abc/index.html;
}

location /xyz {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /xyz/index.html;
}
```